# Corrupted files after transfer from SAMBA share

Tags: linux, windows, samba, data-corruption

I got linux server running SMB 4.3.11 service with some shared resources and several clients running linux (ubuntu) and windows 10. When I download file from share to linux all ok, no problems. But when I download the same file to windows the file appears to be corrupted. Same filesize but not checksum. Not always but the bigger file more chances to be corrupted. What I tried to do:

- Limiting SMB version to latest available SMB3 - no effect
- Setting registry keys: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
  Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache to 1 and
  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size
  to 3 - reduced a bit chance for corruption but didn't solve entirely

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us how you are running Samba, but it doesn't really matter. Your version of Samba is ancient, the latest version is 4.17.2, so you need to upgrade. If that doesn't help (and it probably will), tell us how you are running Samba and provide the output of 'testparm -s'.